# Finding the "tightest" subset in Euclidean space

Tags: cluster-analysis, graph-theory, mathematical-optimization, euclidean-distance

I am given at of points x_1, x_2, ... x_n \in R^d. I wish to find a subset of k points such that the sum of the distances between these k points is minimal. Naively this is an O(n choose k) problem, but I am looking for a faster algorithm.

I can think of two alternative equivalent formulations:

1. The minimal edge weight clique problem: think of the points as a graph, edge weights are the distances, and finding the minimal weight clique. [This is equivalent to maximal edge weight problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2221/heuristics-for-the-minimum-weight-k-clique-problem), which is known to be NP-complete. However, I have the benefit of knowing that my graph is embedded in R^d, and that all the weights are positive, so perhaps that might help?
2. The minimal unconstrained sub-matrix problem: I am given the symmetric distance matrix, and I want to find a kXk minor with minimal sum.

I'd appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious optimization doesn't really require any different formula.

Just greedily find a near-optimal candidate first. Try to refine it in linear time by swapping members. Then do an exhaustive search but stop whenever the new candidates are worse than the greedy-candidate to prune the search space.

E.g.

1. Compute the mean
2. Order objects by squared distance from mean
3. Test all n-k intervals of length k in this order, choose the best
4. For any non-chosen object, try to swap it with one of the chosen objects, if it improves the score

Now you should have a reasonably good candidate for pruning.

Then do an exhaustive search, and stop whenever it is worse than this candidate.

Note: steps 1-3 are an inspiration taken from fast convex hull algorithms.